# Outlook Add-in - AttachmentId is malformed

Tags: outlook, office-js, add-in, outlook-web-addins

We've been having issues intermittently where we get an error when downloading email item content from EWS "AttachmentId is malformed". This is for ItemAttachment (Especially .eml files)

We could not figure why or how this is happening and noticed that the ones that were failing had `+` and `/` in the id's. Searching across the web landed me on [this article](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/office-365-unified-api-mail/). Although this article is from 2015, wondering if this is still happening.

This article blew my mind and made sense (kind of) and implementing the conversion of `+` -> `_` and `/` ->  `-` worked fine, for a while.

We are now receiving the same error 'AttachmentId is malformed' and again could not find why, I removed the custom sanitizer function that replaces these characters and it started working again.

I have no idea what and why is this happening and how to reliably get attachment content. Currently, I've moved the  sanitizer into the catch handler, so if for some reason the AttachmentId fails, we'll retry it by sanitizing it. Will have to keep an eye on how many fail.

Any light on this issue will be really appreciated.

Update 1.0 - Sample Code

Front-end

```
//At this point we've got the email and got the files
//We call EWS only if file.type == Office.MailboxEnums.AttachmentType.Item
//For all other files we call REST endpoint ~ Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + '/v2.0/'......
//Sample code below if only for EWS call

let files = this.email.attachments || [];

files.map(file => {
  this._getEmailContent(file)
  .then(res => {
    return res;
  });
})

//Get content from EWS
_getEmailContent(file, _failed){

  //attachmentId
  //Most of the times this will be fine, but at times when Id has a `+` or `/` if fails, Was expecting the convertToEwsId to handle any sanitization required.

  let attachmentId = Office.context.mailbox.convertToEwsId(file.id, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);
 
  return this.getToken(EWS)
  .then(token => {
    return this.http.post(`${endpoint}/downloadAttachment`,{
      token: token,
      url: Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl,
      id: attachmentId
    },{
       responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    }).then(res => res.data);
  }).catch(err => {
     attachmentId = attachmentId.replace(/\+/g, "_");
     this._getEmailContent(attachmentId, true);
  })
}
```

Back-end

```
[HttpPost]
public DownloadAttachment(Request model){

 var data = service.DownloadAttachment(model);

 if(data == null)
 {
  return BadRequest("Error downloading content...");
 }
 
 return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
   return data;
 }

}

//Inside service
public byte[] DownloadAttachment(Request request){
  var ser = new ExchangeService
  {
    Credentials: request.token,
    Url = request.url
  }

  //Here it fails intermittently, returning AttachmentId is malformed.
  var attachment = ser.GetAttachments(new [] {request.attachmentId}, null, null).First();
  
  if (attachment is FileAttachment)
  {
     FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;
     fileAttachment.Load();
     return fileAttachment.Content; 
  }
   
}
```

Comment: Can you share the client on which you are seeing this issue (OWA, Mac, Windows)? Also can you share the repro step and code snippet for repro?

Comment: This is happening on all platforms. The only way we could reproduce this was by having an “.eml” attachment in an email which just so happens to have “+” in the Id, which makes it hard to reproduce and causing intermittent issues. Also, where can we see the change log for REST api changes? We’ve had few issues lately and would like to  keep updated with any changes happening.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Updated with sample code, hope that helps.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, you are obtaining the email content from Exchange, extracting the attachment ID, and making an Exchange call again to download the attachment. You are not obtaining the attachment ID from Office.context, is that right?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we are getting the attachmentId from office.context, all calls to REST api are fine, it’s only when the attachment is or type ItemAttachment we go back to EWS. Removing the sanitisation has seem to resolve the issue for now, but now we have issues with shared mailbox. I’ve raised another question for accessing shared mailbox attachment over EWS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507176/outlook-add-in-get-shared-mailbox-itemattachment-using-ews

Comment: Are you using Office.context.maibox.item.attachments to get the attachment ID?

Comment: Yes, we get a list of attachments from current context. So, yes. office.context.mailbox.item.attachments => a => a.id

Comment: So it seems like removing the sanitisation has fixed the issue. The original bug seems to have been fixed now. Can we consider this resolved?