# Outlook add-in : Inconsistent @odata.type for .msg files

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Since shared mailbox is not supported via EWS, which we used for downloading `.msg` (ItemAttachments) and all other attachments were downloaded over `REST`

We updated the outlook add-in to filter any 'ItemAttachments' and display them as `un-supported` for shared mailbox, which works fine. But while testing, I found that some `.msg` files were being downloaded via `REST` which was surprising and a concern.

Finally got to re-create and found that:

1. When a `mail` is dragged and dropped within outlook into a compose window, it attaches the attachment as: `@odata.type: #Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemAttachment`
2. When a `.msg` file is dragged and dropped from desktop into a compose window, it attaches the attachment as: `@odata.type: #Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment`

Just wondering why is this? This scenario is on `Outlook web` and `Outlook desktop windows` on `Outlook mac` the attachments are attached as a `.eml` file.

It just makes it confusing to tell the user that some `.msg` files are supported and some are not.

Comment: Hi Amyth, I am seeing .msg being attached as "file" on Outlook Mac, too. Do you mean drag-dropping .eml into Outlook Web attaches it as "file" as well?

Comment: Sorry, this scenario is on web and Windows. I just mentioned the scenario for Mac as it works fine, since mac’s can’t save .msg from desktop app. On web and windows if you DnD an email within the app, it is attached as “item” and if you DnD a “.msg” file from desktop (outside the app) it is attached as “file”. Even the content type changes from “application/vnd.ms-outlook” to “application/octet-stream”. Best way to recreate this is by following the steps as mentioned and then send the mail, once received, save the attachments and check. Let me know if still not clear and will make a video.

Comment: Each client (Windows / Mac / OWA) distinguishes between file / item attachments slightly differently. We recommend that you handle both item and file attachments with REST - it should support both types. Attached message can be downloaded as MIME https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message

Comment: Thanks, since we are currently on REST api v2, will have to think about changing to Graph. Don’t want to have mix of V2 and Graph. But just though, it was strange how a different workflow changed the files on the same client (windows)